# TypeError when creating a website with Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, visual-studio, post

Error message:

> TypeError at /contact contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
>
> Request Method: POST

```py
def contact(request):
    global contact

    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        desc = request.POST.get('desc')
        contact =contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc,date=datetime.today())
        contact.save()
        
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

Comment: Your view **and** model have the same name `contact`. So when you call `contact(name=name, ...)` you are actually calling your view, giving you an error. By convention class names (and hence model names) should be in `PascalCase` not `snake_case` hence your model should be named `Contact`.

Comment: Plus after that you still have that `global contact` and then that `contact =contact` meaning you are overwriting your view! Please follow good practices when naming your variables / functions / classes.